# Ansible causes error 500 on save to database

Tags: django, python-3.x, ansible

When use ansible playbook to setup server, then send post to database cause error 500. If I setup by myself (from start, on terminal commands) it's work without problem.

This is code I use, not full, only part that I was doing by terminal. The system is ubuntu 18.04

```
- hosts: all

  vars:
    host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    site_folder: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/sites/{{ ansible_host }}"
    repo_url: "https://github.com/ForisTale/Django_TDD.git"

  tasks:
    - name: Deadsnakes PPA to get Python 3.7
      apt_repository:
        repo: ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

    - name: make sure required packages are installed
      apt:
        name: ["nginx", "git", "python3.7", "python3.7-venv"]
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Create site folders.
      file:
        path: "{{ site_folder }}"
        state: directory

    - name: Check if .git exists.
      stat:
        path: "{{ site_folder }}/.git"
      register: git_exists

    - name: If .git exists fetch repository.
      command: git fetch
      args:
         chdir: "{{ site_folder }}"
      when: git_exists.stat.exists == True

    - name: If .git don't exists clone repository
      command: git clone {{ repo_url }} .
      args:
        chdir: "{{ site_folder }}"
      when: git_exists.stat.exists == False

    - name: Get local hash commit.
      local_action: command git log -n 1 --format=%H
      register: commmit_hash

    - name: Reset git to actualy used commit.
      command: git reset --hard {{ commmit_hash.stdout }}
      args:
        chdir: "{{ site_folder }}"

    - name: Check if virtualenv exists.
      stat:
        path: "{{ site_folder }}/virtualenv/bin/pip"
      register: venv_exists

    - name: If virtualenv don't exists set it up.
      command: python3.7 -m venv virtualenv
      args:
        chdir: "{{ site_folder }}"
      when: venv_exists.stat.exists == False

    - name: Update requirements.
      command: ./virtualenv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
      args:
        chdir: "{{ site_folder }}"

    - name: Check if .env exists
      stat:
        path: "{{ site_folder }}/.env"
      register: env_exists

    - name: Generate .env
      script: generate_env_file.py
      args:
        chdir: "{{ site_folder }}/deploy_tools/"
        executable: python3
      when: env_exists.stat.exists == False

    - name: Update static files.
      command: ./virtualenv/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
      args:
        chdir: "{{ site_folder }}"

    - name: Update database.
      command: ./virtualenv/bin/python manage.py migrate --noinput
      args:
        chdir: "{{ site_folder }}"
```

After install by ansible-playbook everything looks ok, files are there where they should, only this error 500 on send POST.

Comment: I fail to see anything that would be issuing a post in your playbook.  More input?

Comment: I just find what was wrong. Ansible set ownership of files and folders to root and that prevent any changes (as everything was set up to use user account) to database. Adding command: "chown -R {{ ansible_user}} {{ host }}" with chdir "{{ site_folder }}/.."  fix the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just find what was wrong. Ansible set ownership of files and folders to root and that prevent any changes (as everything was set up to use user account) to database. Adding at the end

```
- name: Change ownership of all files and folders.
  command: "chown -R {{ ansible_user}} {{ host }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ site_folder }}/.."
```

fix the problem.